# Asking A User If They Would Participate In A Survey Before Leaving

Tags: html

When they close their browser or navigate away from my root URL, I'd like to get users' impressions of my website by asking if it's OK to be redirected to a survey, first.

- **DON'T** want to do this if they're just navigating to other pages within website

Trying it out, *Onbeforeunload* only offers the option to leave, or stay.  I'm looking for something that leaves with both options, but provides for a redirect that doesn't necessarily return (or probably anything else), with one of the options.

I've seen this happen before, but can't seem to find the code to implement it.

Finally, my browser pref is Moz, but the technique should probably be universally compatible.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph: `omething that leaves with both options, but provides for a redirect that doesn't necessarily return (or probably anything else), with one of the options.` can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: My head may still be in the "compiler/server-side/application-My head may still be in the "compiler/server-side/application-programming" state, so that's my point of view.  Bear with...  So Onbeforeunload has "hard" STAY and LEAVE options.  The method (that's what you call it, right) I'm looking for would also offer 2 options, one (like "No Thanks") that would just continue navigating/closing, but the other would (like "Yes I will") would issue a redirect (e.g. my survey).  When I said "return", thought of linking back to orig page when leaving the one redirected.  Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do that with the confirm() function in javascript, and you can use window.location to redirect the user where you want.

Comment: Have you tried this inside a `onbeforeunload` event? I don't think it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You can include your logic in function which is called when on Onbeforeunload is triggered.

```
   Onbeforeunload = "return myCustomFunction();"


   function myCustomFunction(){
       //put your redirect logic
   }
```